# serenity.use.unique.browser doesn't work on 1.2.2

Tags: selenium, serenity-bdd, thucydides, cucumber-serenity

I have recently updated my dependencies and this seems to have broken serenity.use.unique.browser as a new browser is used for each scenario now.

I'm using serenity junit 1.2.2 and cucumber 1.1.23.
It was working ok before I updated to these versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1.2.2 onwards you need to use the `serenity.restart.browser.for.each` property, e.g.

`serenity.restart.browser.for.each = feature`

You can set this property to scenario, story, feature, or never